How to get string positions And Length by multi-split filter

I am trying to create what I expect from the subroutine (GetAllPosition).
I don't know where to use RsultOfPostionAndLength in the code to get the expected output
My expectation of the output for (RsultOfPostionAndLength ):
MultiSplit' For {"C", "B", "A"} is:  55-5 '}666['  61-5']777('    67-3')8['  71-6']hhhy('
MultiSplit' For {"A", "B", "C"} is:  27-6 ']1111{'  34-4'}22('    39-7')33333{'  47-3'}4{' 51-3 '}5{' 55-5'}666[' 78-4')99{'  83-5'}999['
    Dim RsultOfPostionAndLength As List(Of String) 'Pattern is Position of String And Length Of Find
    '  'MultiSplit' For {"C", "B", "A"} is:  55-5 '}666['  61-5']777('    67-3')8['  71-6']hhhy('
    '  'MultiSplit' For {"A", "B", "C"} is:  27-6 ']1111{'  34-4'}22('    39-7')33333{'  47-3'}4{' 51-3 '}5{' 55-5'}666[' 78-4')99{'  83-5'}999['
   

 Sub Setup()
        Dim inString As String = "}666[]777([}666[]777(]00[A]1111{C}22(B)33333{C}4{C}5{C}666[A]777(B)8[A]hhhy(B)99{C}999[A]101010}666[]777("
        Dim MultiSplit As String() = {"C", "B", "A"}
        GetAllPosition(1, inString.Length, inString, MultiSplit, 0)
    End Sub

 Sub GetAllPosition(LastIdx As Integer, LastLen As Integer, inString As String, MultiSplit As String(), Level As Integer)
        Dim spl As String() = Split(inString, ",")
        Dim body As String = Mid(inString, LastIdx, LastLen)
        'Dim LastIdx As Integer = spl(0)
        Dim results As New List(Of String)
        Dim Find As String = MultiSplit(Level)
        Dim last As Integer = LastIdx
        Dim index As Integer = -1
        Do Until body.Length <= index
            index = body.IndexOf(Find, index + 1)
            If index = -1 AndAlso body.Length > last Then
                index = body.Length
            End If
            Dim lenTexxt As Integer = Math.Abs(last - index) + 1
            Dim part1 As String = Mid(body, last, lenTexxt)
            Dim part As String = Mid(inString, last, lenTexxt)
            Dim b As Boolean = MultiSplit.Skip(Level + 1).All(Function(c) part.IndexOf(c, comparisonType:=StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
            If b Then
                results.Add(last & "," & lenTexxt & "," & part)
            End If
            last = index + 2
        Loop
        Level += 1
        For Each g In results
            Dim spl2 As String() = Split(g, ",")
            GetAllPosition(spl2(0), spl2(1), inString, MultiSplit, Level)
        Next
    End Sub


Your input string has a very bizarre format. It starts with a closing brace and ends with a left parentheses. Is it in a proprietary format? I don't see the relation between input string and your expected output. Please explain.

Hello My input string can be anything. Do not pay attention to the parentheses. For clarity, it is an example.., I put a picture to clarify the issue for MultiSplit As String() = {"A", "B", "C"} . I want it to be obtained by the method (indexOf or InStr) without using (split method) positions with string length.

You are trying a recursive approach, which is a good thing to do in this situation. My solution uses a Structure to store the results.
Structure ResultItem
    Public Value As String
    Public Position As Integer
    Public Length As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Position}-{Length} ""{Value}"""
    End Function
End Structure

We have to split by the separator corresponding to the current level ("A", "B" or "C"). The last level must be treated differently to end the recursion and also because we do not have to test whether the next level separator is contained.
Sub Test()
    Dim inString As String = "}666[]777([}666[]777(]00[A]1111{C}22(B)33333{C}4{C}5{C}666[A]777(B)8[A]hhhy(B)99{C}999[A]101010}666[]777("
    Dim MultiSplit As String() = {"A", "B", "C"}

    Dim result As List(Of ResultItem) = AllPositions(inString, 0, MultiSplit, 0)

    For Each r As ResultItem In result
        Console.WriteLine(r)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function AllPositions(input As String, index As Integer, separators As String(), level As Integer) As List(Of ResultItem)
    Dim separator As String = separators(level)
    Dim parts As String() =
        Split(input, separator, Compare:=CompareMethod.Text) 'Ignores case

    Dim result = New List(Of ResultItem)()
    If level = separators.Length - 1 Then
        For Each part As String In parts
            Dim item = New ResultItem With {
                .Value = part,
                .Position = index,
                .Length = part.Length
            }
            result.Add(item)
            index += part.Length + separator.Length
        Next
    Else
        Dim nextSeparator As String = separators(level + 1)
        For Each part As String In parts
            If part.Contains(nextSeparator, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                result.AddRange(AllPositions(part, index, separators, level + 1))
            End If
            index += part.Length + separator.Length
        Next
    End If
    Return result
End Function

Output of my console test:
26-6 "]1111{"
33-4 "}22("
38-7 ")33333{"
46-3 "}4{"
50-3 "}5{"
54-5 "}666["
77-4 ")99{"
82-5 "}999["


thank you It was very smart and powerful, it calculated the volume of 30 MB of text in the shortest possible time and delivered it without error. This is the first time I saw such a code that gives results by repeating.

A method (Sub or function) calling itselft is called Recursion. Note I moved Dim nextSeparator ... to before the For Each.

hi. I can't ask the next question on the same topic. What should I do? How can the restriction be removed?

Which restriction? I am talking about recursion, not restriction. Since your problem is recursive in nature, it is very natural to solve it by recursion. You can replace the recursion with loops and stacks, but this makes the algorithm more complicated and offers no advantage when the recursion depth is very low as in your example. If this does not answer your new question, post a new question.

Your answer was used in the program.. I mean I can't post another question. When I press the blue button (ask a question), the conditions for asking are not met.

Does it tell you more about these conditions?

I really don't know what to do about this issue. After posting a few questions and receiving a negative vote, I have been limited for about a year. ...You are very kind.
